# grep - filtrado de filas por valores de columnas

Tags: bash, grep

estoy leyendo funcionalidad de grep pero todo lo que encuentro está relacionado con archivos .txt y no con CSV.
Estoy buscando la forma de hacer un filtrado de valores, por ejemplo, dado el CSV:

```
user,gender,age,native_lang,other_lang
0,M,19,finnish,english swedish german 
1,M,30,urdu,english 
2,F,26,finnish,english swedish german
3,M,20,finnish,english french swedish 
4,F,20,finnish,english swedish 
5,F,29,finnish,english 
6,F,23,swedish,finnish english 
7,F,19,swedish,finnish english french 
8,F,25,finnish,english swedish german russian french estonian
9,F,27,finnish,english italian swedish spanish french
10,F,20,finnish,english 
11,F,26,finnish,english swedish
12,F,27,finnish,english swedish french spanish
13,F,30,finnish,english russian swedish 
14,F,28,finnish,english swedish spanish german 
15,M,34,finnish,swedish english german spanish russian 
16,F,29,finnish,english swedish french spanish estonian
```

Quiero por `user > 10`.

Cómo se especifica el nombre de una columna y la condición?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿qué intentaste?

Comment: La funcionalidad de `grep` está relacionada con la búsqueda de patrones de texto en general, ya sea de un archivo txt o csv. En tu caso no quieres hacer una búsqueda de texto, si no un filtrado por el valor de un campo numérico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La herramienta correcta es `awk`, pero también se puede <strike>ab</strike>usar el `grep`. Simplemente busca por lineas que tienen al menos dos números antes del primer `,`:

```
$ grep '^[0-9][0-9]' file.csv 
10,F,20,finnish,english 
11,F,26,finnish,english swedish
12,F,27,finnish,english swedish french spanish
13,F,30,finnish,english russian swedish 
14,F,28,finnish,english swedish spanish german 
15,M,34,finnish,swedish english german spanish russian 
16,F,29,finnish,english swedish french spanish estonian
```

El `^` en expresiones regulares indica el principio de la linea, y `[0-9]` quiere decir "cualquier número", así que `^[0-9][0-9]` te dará las líneas con al menos dos números al principio.

Comment: gracias. Pensaba que debía indicar de alguna forma el nombre de la columna. He probado con ```$ grep '^[0-9]{2}' file.csv ```, pero no me devuelve resultado y en cambio con ```[0-9][0-9]```, sí. Qué raro...

Comment: @IñigoCatalánEchave es normal: el grep por defecto usa BRE (Basic posix Regular Expressions), un tipo de expresiones regulares que no tienen el formato `{N}` por "N repeticiones del carácter", entonces `^[0-9]{2}` busca por el string literal `{2}`. Necesitas `grep -E` que activa ERE (Extended Regular Expressions), en Linux, también tienes `grep -P` por PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) para usar el `{N}`. Entonces, `grep -P '^\d{2}` o `grep -E '^[0-9]{2}` funcionarían.

Answer (score 3):

En lugar de usar grep, podrías usar [awk](http://www.sromero.org/wiki/linux/aplicaciones/uso_de_awk#:%7E:text=AWK%20es%20una%20herramienta%20de,determinada%20informaci%C3%B3n%20sobre%20las%20mismas.):

```sh
awk -F"," '{ if ($1>10) { print } }' fichero.csv > fichero_filtrado.csv
```

Explicación: awk es un lenguaje para procesar datos Y un comando que suele estar prensente en cualquier distro.

- `-F","` indica que el separador de tokens es la coma
- `'{ if ($1>10) { print } }'` es la operación a realizar: si el token en la primera posición es un valor mayor que 10, entonces imprime la línea
- `fichero.csv`es el fichero original
- las líneas que pasan el filtro se guardarán en `fichero_filtrado.csv`

Como nota final, si quieres mantener el header, puedes modificar la condición para quedarte con la línea número 1:

```
{ if ($1>10 || NR==1) { print } }
```

Que se podría simplificar a

```
awk -F"," '($1>10 || NR==1)' fichero.csv > fichero_filtrado.csv
```

aunque no sea tan evidente

Comment: `awk -F"," '{ if ($1>10) { print } }'` puede simplificarse a simplemente `awk -F, '$1>10'`. `print` es la acción por defecto cuando una condición es cierta.

Answer (score 1):

Agrego un par de alternativas, una con `grep` y otra más versátil que no requiere del uso de `awk`:

```
# Generamos el archivo de prueba
echo "user,gender,age,native_lang,other_lang
0,M,19,finnish,english swedish german 
1,M,30,urdu,english 
2,F,26,finnish,english swedish german
3,M,20,finnish,english french swedish 
4,F,20,finnish,english swedish 
5,F,29,finnish,english 
6,F,23,swedish,finnish english 
7,F,19,swedish,finnish english french 
8,F,25,finnish,english swedish german russian french estonian
9,F,27,finnish,english italian swedish spanish french
10,F,20,finnish,english 
11,F,26,finnish,english swedish
12,F,27,finnish,english swedish french spanish
13,F,30,finnish,english russian swedish 
14,F,28,finnish,english swedish spanish german 
15,M,34,finnish,swedish english german spanish russian 
16,F,29,finnish,english swedish french spanish estonian " > /tmp/pr.csv

# Filtramos (-v) lo que empiece por un único dígito (<10)
grep -v '^[0-9],' /tmp/pr.csv

# Iteramos el contenido ignorando la advertencia cuando $user no contiene números
while IFS="," read -r user resto
do
    # Si se cumple la condición mostramos el contenido de la línea
    (( user >= 10 )) 2> /dev/null && echo $user,$resto
done < /tmp/pr.csv

# En una línea
while IFS=, read -r user resto; do (( user >= 10 ))2>/dev/null && echo $user,$resto ; done < /tmp/pr.csv
```